# How to style Radio input based on "Checked" value

Tags: css, radio-button

How can I add a CSS style to this Radio button's IMG, based on the checked="checked" characteristic?

```
<div id="edit-attributes-24-42-wrapper" class="form-item">
  <label for="edit-attributes-24-42" class="option">
    <input type="radio" class="form-radio" checked="checked" value="42" name="attributes[24]" id="edit-attributes-24-42">
    <img class="radio_image" src="/sites/default/files/imagecache/radio_thumb/days-3.png">
    <div class="radio_image_text">
      Radio Button text, hidden by display:none in CSS
    </div>    
  </label>
</div>
```

Ideally, I'd like to add a style class "selected" to the `<img class="radio_image" src="/sites/default/files/imagecache/radio_thumb/days-3.png">` portion of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checked attribute itself qualifies for selection of radio.

```
input.form-radio:checked + img {
    border:5px solid;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wGA6t/)

Sample Html

```
<div id="edit-attributes-24-42-wrapper" class="form-item">
    <label for="edit-attributes-24-42" class="option">
        <input type="radio" class="form-radio" value="42" name="attributes[24]" id="edit-attributes-24-42">
        <img class="radio_image" src="/sites/default/files/imagecache/radio_thumb/days-3.png">
        <div class="radio_image_text">Radio Button text, hidden by display:none in CSS</div>

        <input type="radio" class="form-radio" value="42" name="attributes[24]" id="edit-attributes-24-42">
        <img class="radio_image" src="/sites/default/files/imagecache/radio_thumb/days-3.png">
        <div class="radio_image_text">Radio Button2 text, hidden by display:none in CSS</div>

    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! I just added this to my CSS and it works very nicely in FF, chrome, and IE! Thanks!

Comment: one more question... how would I modify the CSS if I wanted the "checked" attribute to instead add a class to the form-item div (the top-most div)?

Comment: Thats little bit tricky. I dont think we cannot do that event with CSS3. i.e applying a parent element style based on its child. You should try using javascript or jquery or any other DOM scripting, to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You can't add a class with CSS only, but you could target the element you want with:

```
input[checked=checked] + img{
    /* style here */
}
```

giving it the same style as your selected class.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/shP2r/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Normally, each browser render the radio with its own shape.

you can use this for help styling radio buttons at the top of the below link:

http://metroui.org.ua/forms.php